# Way to limit one search match and no limit on others - HQL

Tags: java, sql, hql, limit

I have a table that has a flag like IorA. Possible values or 'I' or 'A'.

I have a hibernate query like ' select c from MyClass where `.

I need to limit records that match IorA to 'I' in the query and no limit on 'A'.
Union does not work in HQL. Any other way around?

Comment: Why Union doesn't work for you?

Comment: I don't think Hibernate allows Union.

Comment: Right, It doesn't. I was talking about native query. If it is an option.

Comment: So with Native SQL, we would not have all Hibernate Entity related optimizations and performances. Right? Need to sacrifice?

Answer (score 1):

use a subquery:

```
select * from table
where flag = 'a'
union all
select * from (
select * from table
where flag = 'l'
limit 3
) t1
```

Comment: Union is not allowed in hql. Its not regular SQL.

Comment: the only way i know is native sql

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know is `native SQL` query with union (could be named). Other option (very often it is ok) is to use two separate queries.

Comment: So with Native SQL, we would not have all Hibernate Entity related optimizations and performances. Right?

Comment: What performance improvements are you talking about? Well written SQL should not have any problems. You can also map results to the Entity. More info [there](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)